# How do I pass a string or data object between two view controllers?

Tags: ios, iphone, string, path, uinavigationcontroller

In my last question I asked how to best send a string from one view controller to another, both which were on a navigation stack:
[Pass string from tableviewcontroller to viewcontroller in navigation stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898860/pass-string-from-tableviewcontroller-to-viewcontroller-in-navigation-stack)

However I just realised I can either pass the path to the file in the app's document's folder as the first (the table view) has already accessed the data in the file should I pass viewcontroller the data to the pushed VC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing a reference would be less overhead than reinitializing a fresh object in the child view controller.

Set up a [`retain` property](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html) in the child view controller for the `NSString` instance.

In the parent view controller, instantiate the child view controller and set its string property equal to the string you want to pass it:

```
childViewController.myStringProperty = parentViewControllerString;
```

As this increments the `retain` count of the string, you're not recreating the object, just keeping a reference to it.

You could instead retain an `NSData` instance, if you wanted. This would be less of a hit than recreating it in the child v.c.

Comment: Absolutely, that was what I was suggesting, that you retain the object in the pushed view controller.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is that you should pass say the NSData object to the pushed view controller.  If it's not too large it will save you from loading it again.